# how to hide a component in react js after a few second

Tags: reactjs

hi I design this alert component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'antd';

export default function CustomAlert (props) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {
                props.visible ?
                    <Alert message={props.message} style={{textAlign: 'right', direction: 'rtl' , position: 'fixed', width:'100%', zIndex:'100'}} closable afterClose={props.handleClose}/>

                    :
                    null
            }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

but I want to hide the alert after 5 second. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an answer with css styling but here is a better answer:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'antd';

export default function CustomAlert(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {

            props.handleClose();
        },5000 )
    }, [])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {props.visible ? (
                <Alert
                    message={props.message}
                    style={{
                        textAlign: "right",
                        direction: "rtl",
                        position: "fixed",
                        width: "100%",
                        zIndex: "100"
                    }}
                    closable
                    afterClose={props.handleClose}
                />
            ) : null}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: you could consider adding the cleanup function of setInterval on component unmount

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout to auto close the Alert something like this. Find the working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-lake-kp2gx)

```
  export default function CustomAlert(props) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(props.visible);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    visible &&
      setTimeout(() => {
        setVisible(false);
      }, props.closeAfter);
  }, [props.closeAfter, visible, setVisible]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {visible ? (
        <Alert
          message={props.message}
          style={{
            textAlign: "right",
            direction: "rtl",
            position: "fixed",
            width: "100%",
            zIndex: "100"
          }}
          closable
          afterClose={props.handleClose}
        />
      ) : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

And use the component like this in other files,

```
<CustomAlert visible message="Test Message" closeAfter={5000} />
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't show my alert anymore :(

Comment: It worked for me, Did you pass the visible prop as true to CustomAlert?

Comment: I use it like this <CustomAlert message={this.state.message} visible={this.state.visible} handleClose={() => {this.setState({visible: false})}} closeAfter={5000}/>  and it worked before

Comment: Is 'this.state.visible' true?

Comment: This is the codesnadbox I used, please check https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-lake-kp2gx

Comment: yes its true and it workes in the way that I wrote in my question (I mean without setTimeout)

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to convey, do you want to auto-close the alert without setTimeout?

Comment: when I do the console.log(props.visible) it logs true and its true but the code doesn't work

Comment: I would suggest you check the code sandbox I pasted and compare it with your code. The code sandbox has a working example.

Comment: I finally understand what is your code's problem for my project. It is better to use setInterval instead of setTimeout. I will post my answer.thanks.

Comment: ahh! Is it because on re-renders it's not showing the Alert?

Comment: actually it shows the alert in the first 5 second of running the project and after that it doesn't work. But setInterval  check it every 5 seconds (I hope my explanation is correct)

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with this style:

```
.alert{
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 15s forwards;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 15s forwards;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 15s forwards;
    /* Opera */
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 15s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    text-align: right ;
    direction: rtl ;
    position:  fixed;
    width: 100% ;
    z-index: 100;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index: -100;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
        z-index: -100;
    }
}
```